# How to add/import and control 3d object to visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, 3d, visual-studio-2008

I try to make a project in visual studio 2008 using c++ lang. The project i want to make required to import 3d model like blender file to visual studio 2008 and make a control so i can rotate and mini/maximize the object.
The project based description is a a 3d planet model and control to start/stop auto rotating, manually rotating, and maxi-minimize the planet

I have search youtube and every documentation i know, but its hardly to find the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.